# Moving Oracle procs out of packages

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hi we have legacy java app which connects to Oracle dB.  There are lots of procs in different packages.  I was thinking of moving them out of Oracle packages andake them as standalone procs.. Advantages are
1. There is a possibility that 2 developers may be working on same package in different procs hence there is a chance of overwriting each other's code. 
2. As procs in packages are used in many places hence making a change to proc will impact most of the places in the app as the overall package gets compiled. If we have change in standalone proc then the change impact is limited to where it is used within the app.  As in this case only the standalone proc would compile.

Are there really any advantages for having Oracle  packages apart from organizing procs in one place.  Are there any performance benefits?.

Thx in advance

Comment: Recompiling a package will only have a wider effect if you have stateful packages; which cause all existing sessions to get an error on next access as the state is discarded. Package state should generally be avoided if possible; and if you do rely on state then moving to standalone procs would be an issue anyway. And surely you have source control that would prevent users overwriting each others changes (or at least allow them to be merged)? It's also possible, though awkward, to split a package into multiple source files.

Comment: The arguments used against packages could be applied to any programming language; why should your Java code be organized but not your PL/SQL code?  Other than "making it work", keeping the code well-organized is probably the most important thing a programmer can do.  You shouldn't sacrifice clean code to accommodate a poor programmer or process that can't handle simple text differences.

Comment: Will you also be moving your Java code out of classes and into standalone scripts (unless there is a performance reason not to) in case two developers need to work on the same class?